# Why is this function defined on $\mathbb{R}$ ?

Tags: analysis, implicit-function-theorem

I have to justify why from the equation $x^3-3x+2+ye^y=0$ a function $y=f(x)$ is implicitly defined on $\mathbb{R}$.

When we use the implicit function theorem, do we not get that the above holds in a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ ?

How can we justify that in this case?

Comment: It's not implicitely defined on all $\mathbb R$.  Why do you claim it is?

Comment: Here is the statement (in german) : https://imgur.com/gHxhDJG So is the statement wrong? @fleablood

Comment: I think "define on $\mathbb R$" is implied to mean defined on a subset of $\mathbb R$; not all of $\mathbb R$.

Comment: ... or the problem is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

It is not.

Note that $y \mapsto -y e^y$ has a $\max$ of $e$, hence if $x^3-3x+2 >e$, there is no value of $y$ that satisfies the equation.

Furthermore, when $x^3-3x+2$ lies in $(0,e)$ there are two values of $y$ that satisfy the equation.

**Addendum**:

Let $f(x) = x^3-3x+2$, $g(y) = -y e^y$. The idea is that given $x$, we want
to find a unique $y$ such that $f(x) = g(y)$.

A small amount of work shows (i) $\lim_{y \to -\infty} g(y) = 0$, (ii) $g$ is strictly increasing on $(-\infty,-1]$, (iii) $g$ is strictly decreasing on $[1,\infty)$ and (iv) $\lim_{x \to \infty} g(y) = -\infty$. Combining these, we see that the only values of $\alpha$ for which $g(y) = \alpha$ has a unique
solution are $\alpha \le 0$.

Consequently, we want to find values of $x$ such that $f(x) \le 0$.
A small amount of work shows that $f(x) \le 0$ **iff** $x \le -2$ or $x = 1$.

Hence we can uniquely define a function $h$ on $(-\infty, -2) \sup \{1\}$ that
satisfies $f(x) = g(h(x))$.

If we are willing to drop the uniqueness, we can extend the definition, then the
domain becomes $\{x | f(x) \le e \}$ which consists of two intervals.

Comment: Here is the statement (in german) : https://imgur.com/gHxhDJG So is the statement wrong?

Comment: @MaryStar: Hi Mary, unfortunately my linguistic abilities are severely limited and constrained to English (I can't even speak my 'native' language).

Comment: Perhaps the intent was to define the function on $x \le 2$?

Comment: Would the statement hold for these $x$ values? If yes, how could we justify the assumption?

Comment: @MaryStar: Ignore my last comment, I added some notes to the answer above.

Comment: How does it imply that $g(y)=\alpha$ has a unique solution for $\alpha\geq 0$ ?

Comment: I goofed. Given me a few minutes to correct it.

Comment: Repaired. Hopefully there are no serious mistakes remaining.

Comment: Do we have that in the interval $(-\infty, -1)$ the function is positiv and in the interval $(-1,\infty)$ is again positiv and then negativ. 
So the equation $g(y)=\alpha$ when $\alpha$ is positiv has no unique solution but when $\alpha$ is non-positiv the equation has a unique solution. Is this correct why we have to take $\alpha\leq 0$?

Comment: Try plotting $f,g$ and it will be clear.

Answer (score 0):

Did the problem actually say "show that", or was it more like "determine whether"?

In fact $x^3-3x+2+ye^y=0$ does *not* define a function from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$. Say $f(y)=ye^y$. Then $\lim_{y\to\infty}f(y)=\infty$ and $\lim_{y\to-\infty}f(y)=0$. *So* there exists $\alpha$ such that $f(y)>\alpha$ for all $y$.

There exists $x$ such that $x^3-3x+2=-\alpha$, and for this $x$ there does not exist $y$ with $x^3-3x+2+ye^y=0$.

Comment: Here is the statement (in german) : https://imgur.com/gHxhDJG So is the statement wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

With the help of the so called Lambert function

$$
Ye^Y = X \Leftrightarrow  Y = W(X)
$$

we have

$$
y = W(3x-x^3-2)
$$

but this don't represents the full set associated to

$$
f(x,y)= x^3-3x+2+ye^y = 0
$$

Attached a plot showing in (blue $\cup$ red) the set associated to $f(x,y)=0$ and in red the set associated to $y = W(3x-x^3-2)$

[image]

Concluding, $f(x,y)=0$ does not represents an implicit function.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the problem wants to assume that $x\geq  0$.  Then the equation does define a function on ${\bf R}_{\geq 0}$

Comment: There are multiple solutions for $x \in (0,e)$. It does not define a function there.

Comment: $x\leq -2$ should work.